# Memory issue when using CWLSynthesizeSingleton.h

Tags: cocoa, singleton

I'm using [CWLSynthesizeSingleton.h](https://github.com/incbee/CWLSynthesizeSingleton/blob/master/CWLSynthesizeSingleton.h) to create a singleton. But when analyzing the source code in Xcode it shows this error:

```
Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected
```

on this line

```
CWL_SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS_WITH_ACCESSOR(MyManager, sharedManager)
```

I do not use ARC in this project. Any suggestion how to fix that? Should it just ignore that?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: don't use that code, it's old and no longer recommended. The correct way to create singletons these days is to use `dispatch_once`:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [(id)[super alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

If you want to prevent a user of your class from allocating an instance directly, then use the `unavailable` compiler attribute in your header for those methods you don't want called:

```
+ (instancetype)alloc __attribute__((unavailable("alloc not available, call sharedInstance instead")));
- (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("init not available, call sharedInstance instead")));
+ (instancetype)new __attribute__((unavailable("new not available, call sharedInstance instead")));
```